# $_SESSION['ageAccept'] is set, but is ignored?

Tags: php, authentication, session-variables, verify

I am about to pull out hair. I have done this before and it worked/works still on that page. It is not a difficult concept, but for some reason I am getting strange results. By that I mean that when I click the "I'm 18+ button" it does take me to the home.php page. If I refresh the home.php it takes me back to index.php. If I click on the news.php it takes me back to index.php. Pretty much any action after home.php loads takes me back to index.php. I have no clue why.

I want a simple age check page (index.php) that will require the user to click the "I'm 18+ button" or the "I'm NOT 18" button which will redirect them to Google.

I have just started the construction of the site so I only have 2 pages available (Home.php, News.php) and below is the PHP codes I have at the top of the page. (please note I have searched this site quite a bit and none of the solutions I have found have worked. If the question was answered and I have missed it I am sorry, believe me if I could have just read the answer I would have.)

The index.php:

```
<?php

session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['ageAccept'])) {
    header('Location: home.php');
    exit;
}

if(!empty($_POST)) {

    if(isset($_POST['ageAccept'])) {
        $_SESSION['ageAccept'] = true;
        header('Location: home.php');
        exit;
    } else { header('Location: http://www.google.com'); }
}

?>
```

The home.php & news.php:

```
<?php

session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['ageAccept'])) {
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit;
}
?>
```

on the index.php page I am using a simple form:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="I am 18+ (ENTER)" class="enter" name="ageAccept">
<input type="submit" value="NOT 18+ (Leave)" class="enter" name="ageFail">
</form>
```

Comment: On `index.php` does that HTML lie before your PHP code or after it?

Comment: It is before Hanky, always before was what I was told. I am new to PHP, only about 3 weeks in. All the PHP codes are at the start of the pages before even <!DOCTYPE html>.

Comment: what does var_dump($_POST); give?

Comment: Other than any small possible typo, your logic seems to be correct and so the does your code. Try some debugging and prit_r($_SESSION); on home and news.php right under session_start(); and kill the execution there, see if theres any value

Comment: Ok Hanky I will try that thank you. Marabutt it came out with: array (size=1) 'Accept' => string 'I am 18+(ENTER)' (length=16)

Comment: How can it be `Accept=>`, it has to be `ageAccept`. See if your actual submit button name matches with your `if` statement. That could very well be the issue

Comment: So here is a fun fact... PHP codes that are commented out in HTML evidently still run. I had an input button that unset($_SESSION['Accept'] and even though the commenting out removed that button it's function still ran. Removing the comment fixed the code.

Comment: Thank you Hanky, that was an error, but even fixing that did not help. Strange thing is that comment still had ageAccept and it still, even commented out, ran.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well thank you to everyone who helped me figure this out! I actually found my error and it was a rather tricky one. When commenting out a HTML tag, if that tag contains PHP codes those codes will not be commented out by the HTML tag! Example:

```
<!-- <h1><?php echo $title ?></h1>-->
```

While the code will turn gray (if your editor supports that function) the PHP code is in fact live! I have not tested whether or not putting the // in front of the PHP code would comment both out, but it was just simpler to rip it out. :P

Again thank you all for your help, I actually learned different things form asking this question, so all comments were greatly appreciated!

Comment: What was the code that you had commented out that was causing this issue?

Comment: <--<form action=<?php header('Location: index.php); unset($_SESSION['ageAccept']; ?>><input type="submit" value="Not 18+"></form>--> Something along those lines, it has long since been deleted so can't remember the exact code.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine so I would suggest doing some debugging.  It's problem an issue with your `php.ini`.  Start by placing the following code under your `session_start()`

```
echo session_id();
```

Check if that id is the same on all the pages.  If it's not in your `php.ini` you should check the value of `session.cookie_domain`.  This is normally blank.

Also check the value of `session.save_path` in your `php.ini` to see if this is correct.

Finally do you have a .htaccess file?  Rewrite rules in there can mess up sessions.

Comment: The session id echoed out the same, but as far as php.ini goes that is a new one to me. Could you please tell me where that it? I am running WAMP on Windows 7 as a test environment.

Comment: Ok figured out the php.ini and all checked out, even deleted the session files in the tmp directory. Same problem.